# Long Division when dividend and divisor are of same size (same number of digits)

Tags: algorithms

I want to know if there is some optimized method (constant complexity preferred) to obtain the quotient when the dividend and the divisor contain the same number of digits. I know about algorithm D of "The Art of Computer Programming" but there Knuth describes how to find quotient digit when the dividend is $n+1$ in length and divisor is $n$. Is there any method of finding the quotient digit when they both are of the same length? Obviously I can search linearly from $1$ to $base$ or use Binary search for the same but I was looking for something more optimal as my Base is very large $(\approx 10^{18})$

Comment: Have you read this thread at Stack Overflow, yet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942466/what-algorithm-should-i-use-for-high-performance-large-integer-division

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find anything useful as far as my problem is concerned.